# Includes LIKE multiple values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, include

I want to find multiple values in an array. When searching, I want to be able to use something like a LIKE statement from SQL.

`arr = ['end', 'start_date', 'hello', 'end_dt', 'pub_date']`

When I do:

`let el = arr.find(a => a.includes('date') || a.includes('dt'));`

Right now it only returns the first value it finds, `start_date`

I need it to return:

```
start_date
end_dt
pub_date
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Use `filter` instead of `find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns only the first match for the return conditions.

Use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let arr = ['end', 'start_date', 'hello', 'end_dt', 'pub_date']
console.log(arr.filter(a => a.includes('date') || a.includes('dt')))
```